# Error: "missing 1 required positional argument" while defining an abstract method even though I put the parameter

Tags: python, openai-gym

so I am trying to learn ai, and I am trying to make an ai model. To do this, I have to define some abstract functions that the ai module needs. here is the code:

Ai module class: https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py

Child class (the one I am trying to define the abstract method in)

```
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import numpy as np
import random
from abc import abstractmethod
class ShowerEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        # Actions we can take, down, stay, up
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        # Temperature array
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0]), high=np.array([100]))
        # Set start temp
        self.state = 38 + random.randint(-3,3)
        # Set shower length
        self.shower_length = 60
    @Env.step
    def step(self, action):
        # Apply action
        # 0 -1 = -1 temperature
        # 1 -1 = 0 
        # 2 -1 = 1 temperature 
        self.state += action -1 
        # Reduce shower length by 1 second
        self.shower_length -= 1 
        
        # Calculate reward
        if self.state >=37 and self.state <=39: 
            reward =1 
        else: 
            reward = -1 
        
        # Check if shower is done
        if self.shower_length <= 0: 
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        # Apply temperature noise
        #self.state += random.randint(-1,1)
        # Set placeholder for info
        info = {}
        
        # Return step information
        return self.state, reward, done, info
    @Env.render
    def render(self):
        # Implement viz
        pass
    @Env.reset
    def reset(self):
        # Reset shower temperature
        self.state = 38 + random.randint(-3,3)
        # Reset shower time
        self.shower_length = 60 
        return self.state
```

implementation:

```js
from ShowerEnv import ShowerEnv
import time

env = ShowerEnv()
while True:
    print(str(env.state) + ',' + str(env.action_space.sample()))
    time.sleep(1)
```

I am trying to define the function 'step' but it says, "step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action'".

Comment: Don't put it in a code snippet, it doesn't run.

Comment: Java? Where Java executors

Comment: you use `@Env.step` as a decorator but it is not a decorator, from the doc `Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or is derived from it.`

Comment: Next time post your exception stack trace, but I can make a fair guess that the decorator `@Env.step`, which is a higher order function, expected two arguments: `self` and `action`. Applying the decorator to the `step` method only gives it 1 argument, so it raises an exception that it needed 1 more argument. But more to the point, I don't see why you have these decorators to begin with. In all the examples I've seen, the concrete class never needed decorators for concrete methods, only inherit from the abstract class.

Comment: whenever I dont use decorators, it totally ignores the funciton

Comment: _Even though I put the parameter_ - In your definition, sure, but where is this class actually instantiated and used?

Comment: I will put it in the discription